# IllegalstateException GoogleCamer crash on capture video intent screen

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, fatal-error, video-recording

Below is the observed crash stacktrace, which occurs 
everytime I press record on the capture video screen provided by google

```
(launched using intent - Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE))
```

on Nexus 5 - 6.0.1. and camera app version - 3.1.021(2428808-30)

04-13 19:21:0

```
694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 9694
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rect.width must be nonnegative
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNonnegative(Preconditions.java:100)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.params.MeteringRectangle.<init>(MeteringRectangle.java:139)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.one.v2.AutoFocusHelper.regionsForNormalizedCoord(AutoFocusHelper.java:155)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.one.v2.AutoFocusHelper.aeRegionsForNormalizedCoord(AutoFocusHelper.java:186)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.one.OneVideoImpl.triggerFocusAndMeterAtPoint(OneVideoImpl.java:362)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.module.videointent.state.StateReadyForCapture$7.processEvent(StateReadyForCapture.java:219)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.module.videointent.state.StateReadyForCapture$7.processEvent(StateReadyForCapture.java:200)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.fsm.StateMachineImpl.processEvent(StateMachineImpl.java:117)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.module.videointent.VideoIntentModule$3$1.onSingleTapUp(VideoIntentModule.java:408)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:635)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.ui.PreviewOverlay.onTouchEvent(PreviewOverlay.java:250)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9300)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.libraries.stitch.lifecycle.ObservableActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(ObservableActivity.java:227)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
04-13 19:21:03.523 9694-9694/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
```

3.523 9